# Unable to re-parent a folder of reports using REST API

Tags: rest-api, reports-api, reports-folder

Is it intentional that I get such an error `Folder parent cannot be part of a patch request body.` when I try to re-parent a folder using [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_folders_ops.htm)?

According to the documentation `PATCH` allows to change name and label even though in the request body one can specify the parent Id.

Comment: I ran into this limitation recently as well. When you read the actual sObject documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_folder.htm it says that the ParentId can only be set on create